# Python Subprocess efficiently check if child process terminated

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running this bash cmd using subprocess to start jmeter in a remote system.

```
['java', '-server', '-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError', '-Xms512m', '-Xmx512m', '-XX:+UseG1GC', 
'-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=250', '-XX:G1ReservePercent=20', '-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom', 
'-Xms1024m', '-Xmx1024m', '-jar', '/jmeter/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar', '-n', 
'-t', '/code/jmx_file.jmx', '-JReplica_ID=1', '-JService_Name=execution-b063818a',
'-l', '/code/logs/logs.log']
```

Now I am using `while loop` to check the child processes are terminated are not and if terminated flush log files like below

```
sub_proc = subprocess.Popen(
                    bash_cmd,
                    stdout=proc_log,
                    stderr=proc_log
                )
# while the process is still running, dump the data to the file.
while sub_proc.poll() is None:
    proc_log.flush()
    os.fsync(proc_log)
sub_proc.wait()
```

But this `while loop` is shooting my process to 100% CPU utilization .

I want to know if there is any other way to efficiently check if child process terminated or not like above to reduce the CPU usage.

Comment: You already ``wait`` efficiently for the child to terminate... after the while loop. So *why* do you flush the log files in an infinite loop? The subprocess is handling I/O to them, not yours.

Comment: Sorry not following you here, you mean while loop is not needed here to check the child terminated or not , or while loop is needed but not the flush . I think flush is not creating the spike in CPU usage here

Comment: ``sub_proc.wait()`` will already check that the child terminated. I do not see why you would ``flush`` and ``fsync`` in the first place. So I cannot say if you can remove it, since apparently you had a reason to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Add sleep to your `while loop`, otherwise its bound to use as much CPU as it can:

```
from time import sleep
sub_proc = subprocess.Popen(
                    bash_cmd,
                    stdout=proc_log,
                    stderr=proc_log
                )
# while the process is still running, dump the data to the file.
while sub_proc.poll() is None:
    proc_log.flush()
    os.fsync(proc_log)
    sleep(0.05) #change to acceptable value
sub_proc.wait()
```

You are checking if its running with `sub_proc.poll() is None` in a correct manner.